# PHP Как cоединить части строки всеми возможными комбинациями

Tags: php

Есть строка разбирая на слова и помещенная в массив:

```
$parts=Array('yamaha','dtx', '400');
```

Есть варианты соединителей этих слов: тире, пробел, слитное написание

```
$jumpers=Array('-',' ', '');
```

Как красиво получить все возможные варианты объединения слов, через заданные соединители. Сейчас у меня сделано тупо вручную. В данном случае получится 9 вариантов:

```
yamaha-dtx-400
yamaha-dtx 400
yamaha-dtx400
yamaha dtx-400
yamaha dtx 400
yamaha dtx400
yamahadtx-400
yamahadtx 400
yamahadtx400
```

В реальности соединителей может быть не 3, а 4 и тогда количество вариантов резко возрастает. Вручную совсем никак уже.

Понимаю, что как-то через вложенные циклы, но уже 3 часа сижу пробую разные варианты, не получается. Наверняка должно быть какое-то красивое решение. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Конечная задача какая? Парсить сайты по продаже мототехники? Если так, то проще не создавать кучу слов для проверки, а вытягивать все про 'yamaha', канонизировать результаты и сравнивать с эталоном

Comment: Почти. Парсинг прайсов поставщиков. У которых модель может быть указана как угодно.Реальный пример: есть название товара
yamaha dtx400k

В базах у разных поставщиков он может быть записан как:
yamaha dtx-400k
 yamaha dtx 400k
 yamaha dtx400 k

С брендом (yamaha) все просто, он всгда однозначен.
А вот с моделью проблема. Поэтому я бью модель на части: dtx, 400, k а потом ищу все возможные варианты написания.

Comment: обновил ответ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут нужна рекурсия

```
<?php
function make($parts, $jumpers, $tail){
    $part = array_shift($parts);
    if($tail===''){
        make($parts, $jumpers, $part);
        return;
    }
    foreach($jumpers as $jumper){
        if(empty($parts)){
            echo $tail.$jumper.$part.PHP_EOL;
        }else{
            make($parts, $jumpers, $tail.$jumper.$part);
        }
    }
}

$parts=Array('yamaha','dtx', '400');
$jumpers=Array('-',' ', '');

make($parts, $jumpers, '');
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce3881d46cd16c7173c251e24d4382e056a81b0f)

Но меня не оставляет подозрение, что вы пытаетесь закрутить гвоздь отверткой.

**UPD** После уточнения задачи в комментариях

Вы не с того конца беретесь. Вам надо нормализовать прайс лист, а не пытаться найти все возможные варианты.

Как-то так:

```
$price = [['model' => 'Yamaha DT X-400', ...], ...];
foreach ($price as $value){
    $model = mb_strtolower(preg_replace("/[\W_]/","",$value['model']));
    if($model === 'yamahadtx400') echo 'YES!';
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Пример работает как надо, но вот может и вправду проще сначала нормализовать.